# How to append enumerable collection to an existing list in C#

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable, generics

i have three functions which are returning an IEnumerable collection.
now i want to combine all these into one List.
so, is there any method by which i can append items from IEnumerable to a list.
i mean without for each loop?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Well, *something* will have to loop... but in LINQ you could easily use the [`Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) and [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) extension methods:

```
var bigList = list1.Concat(list2).Concat(list3).ToList();
```

Note that this will create a *new* list rather than appending items to an *existing* list. If you want to add them to an existing list, [`List<T>.AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) is probably what you're after:

```
bigList.AddRange(list1);
bigList.AddRange(list2);
bigList.AddRange(list3);
```

Answer (score 10):

If you already have a list:

```
list.AddRange(yourCollectionToAppend);
```

If you have 2 enumerables and haven't created the list yet:

```
firstCollection.Concat(secondCollection).ToList();
```