# How to get the maximum number of members based on users from Azure AD using Graph Api

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am getting the the groups based on users from Microsoft Graph Api. Although I am getting the groups but they are coming to total count of 100.

I tried to use paging technique but it is keep failing. Can someone help me out?

```
 var page = graphClient
                   .Users[uniqueIdentification]
                    .MemberOf
                    .Request()
                    .GetAsync().Result;

        var names = new List<string>();

        names.AddRange(page
                .OfType<Group>()
                .Select(x => x.DisplayName)

        .Where(name => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)));
```

The above code only return top 100.

When I tried below code for paging it got cast error .

Error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Graph.DirectoryObject]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Microsoft.Graph.Group]'.
```

Code:

```
    var group2 = new List<Group>();
        var groupsPage = graphClient.Users[uniqueIdentification].MemberOf.Request().Top(300).GetAsync().Result;
        group2.AddRange((IEnumerable<Group>)groupsPage.CurrentPage);
        while (groupsPage.NextPageRequest != null)
        {
            groupsPage =  groupsPage.NextPageRequest.GetAsync().Result;
            group2.AddRange((IEnumerable<Group>)groupsPage.CurrentPage);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> The  maximum sizes of pages  are 100 and 999 user objects respectively
> and are default .

Some queries are supported only when you use the
`ConsistencyLevel` header set to **`eventual`** and **`$count to true`**

For the error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Graph.DirectoryObject]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Microsoft.Graph.Group]'.
```

It looks like here `group2` is of type list but trying to add/append the page of type Ienumerable  to it which is leading to cast error.(note:list implements Ienumerable (parent) but ienumerable doesn't inherit from list  as Ienumerable can be list, queue ,stack )

```
using System.Linq;
```

While using `var group2 = new List<Group>();`

try to add `.ToList();` or `.Cast<group>().ToList();`  depending on latest or old type of versions   before adding or appending to the group2 of type list

Please check the References to know further details :

1. [List users - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-2)
2. [How to append enumerable collection to an existing list in C# -
   Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067223/how-to-append-enumerable-collection-to-an-existing-list-in-c-sharp)